# Override already loaded scripts/libraries with modern ones - when you cant remove them due closed source code

Tags: javascript, html

Working with a platform that has tons of benefits for a client on the back end and stuff, but the front end is using many outdated libraries that they are not allowing to remove, so I can add new libraries but old ones with the same object names will be loaded on the front end.

So I have been wondering if it's possible to somehow override them?

For example, they use Owl Carousel v1 but it's missing so many good features of v2, is it possible to somehow "destroy" each loaded instance of v1 and reinit with v2?

Yes, this question is "WTF" inducing, but sometimes we have to work with the platform that has been given.

Comment: depends on the library, I've used datatables.net and just by starting a new instance of the library it overrides the previously running instance. however the approach will vary a lot depending on your dependencies.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. But can you simply bundle your own library and don't use window global instance?

Comment: @Mario I think you mean loading newer versions instead of the old ones. not on top of it - is it? For example, it not like you would have two include 2 libraries at the same time? (which is in my case).

Comment: @apple, yeah, hard to understand as the normal way is to just have access to "head" or "footer" to stop the old library from loading and include a new one. but have a case here where many areas are not editable.

Comment: @MaximusLight I meant loading v2 in a page that had v1 already loaded, what do you mean by on top of it? my use case was a site using datatables in the global scripts  and then loading myself a newer version of datatables importing it inside my module

Comment: @MaximusLight So, can you simply bundle your own library and don't use window global instance?